# How do I turn off git autocorrect?

Tags: git, autocorrect

When I typo a git command, such as typing `git git checkout myfile` (note the extra "git") I get the following output:

```
WARNING: You called a Git command named 'git', which does not exist.
Continuing under the assumption that you meant 'init'
in 0.1 seconds automatically...
usage: git init [-q | --quiet] [--bare] [--template=<template-directory>] [--shared[=<permissions>]] [<directory>]
```

So git assumes I meant init, and gives me all of 0.1 seconds to see the mistake before it moves forward. Not cool git!

How do I turn this "feature" off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To see the setting of autocorrect, type:

`git config help.autocorrect`

Per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

*help.autocorrect is actually an integer which represents tenths of a second. So if you set it to 50, Git will give you 5 seconds to change your mind before executing the autocorrected command.*

To turn this off, use the command:

`git config --global help.autocorrect 0`

Comment: Nice! With `help.autocorrect` set to `0`, git still prints out a hint, such as `git: 'git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'. The most similar command is init`. And when looking for similar commands, it also searches aliases; eg I have `psoh` aliased to mean `push origin HEAD`, and if I mistype it as `psoj`, it will suggest my alias.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, you may also use `-c help.autocorrect=0` as a parameter to any Git command. For example:

```
git -c help.autocorrect=0 svn find-rev 5e2272613fa
```

It is useful for scripts as you don't modify the environment you are running in.

In this case, unless git-svn is installed, Git would fail to recognize the `svn` command and try to fall back to `serve` instead, which might be disastrous in a script.

Answer (score 2):

The up-to-date way to turn that off (in 2020) is with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021): "`git $cmd $args`, when `$cmd` is *not* a recognised subcommand, by default tries to see if `$cmd` is a typo of an existing subcommand and optionally executes the corrected command if there is only one possibility, depending on the setting of `help.autocorrect`.

**The users can now disable the whole thing**, including the cycles spent to find a likely typo, by setting the configuration variable to '**`never`**'.

See [commit 644bb95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644bb953ce3251f2868ece6b767949828fa32e44) (25 Nov 2020) by [Drew DeVault (`ddevault`)](https://github.com/ddevault).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 78abcff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/78abcff222d2d9cb05776bac39f7dc6a84b8f809), 14 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`help.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/644bb953ce3251f2868ece6b767949828fa32e44): `help.autocorrect=never` means "do not compute suggestions"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Drew DeVault</sup>

> While `help.autocorrect` can be set to 0 to decline auto-execution of possibly mistyped commands, it still spends cycles to compute the suggestions, and it wastes screen real estate.
>
> Update `help.autocorrect` to accept the string "`never`" to just exit with error upon mistyped commands to help users who prefer to never see suggested corrections at all.
>
> While at it, introduce "`immediate`" as a more readable way to immediately execute the auto-corrected command, which can be done with negative value.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/644bb953ce3251f2868ece6b767949828fa32e44/Documentation/config/help.txt#L11-L18):

> If git detects typos and can identify exactly one valid command similar
> to the error, git will automatically run the intended command after
> waiting a duration of time defined by this configuration value in
> deciseconds (0.1 sec).
>
> - If this value is 0, the suggested corrections
>   will be shown, but not executed.
> - If it is a negative integer, or "`immediate`", the suggested command
>   is run immediately.
> - If "never", suggestions are not shown at all.
>
> The default value is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Note the default value for [`help.autocorrect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-helpautoCorrect) is 0.

You can also set it to a greater value than 1: it uses deciseconds, so 10 would be 1 second, 30 would be 3 seconds, and so on.

Note that starting  Git 2.14, the warning and a continuation message will change.
See [commit 968b1fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/968b1fe263f9dfec65be4598e4f0dd76f1692551) (21 Jun 2017) by [Marc Branchaud (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit aca226e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aca226e6e9cb691acb7a7899efb93ec8d819861f), 26 Jun 2017)</sup>

Before, with `help.autoCorrect = 15`:

```
WARNING: You called a Git command named 'lgo', which does not exist.
   Continuing under the assumption that you meant 'log'
   in 1.5 seconds automatically...
```

After:

```
WARNING: You called a Git command named 'lgo', which does not exist.
Continuing in 1.5 seconds, assuming that you meant 'log'.
```